# ros2 access current LaunchConfiguration

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm in the middle of migrating a ROS1 app of mine to ROS2 and I'm currently trying to convert a `.launch` file to a python script.

I want to be able to pass a command line argument to the script and then get its value in the `generate_launch_description` call.

This is how I currently pass extra arguments to the LaunchDescription:

```
run_rqt_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(name="run_rqt",
                                    default_value="True",
                                    description="Launch RQT?")
run_rviz_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(name="run_rviz",
                                     default_value="True",
                                     description="Launch RVIZ?")

if run_rqt:
    rqt = Node(...)
    l.append(rqt)
if run_rviz:
    rviz = Node(...)
    l.append(rviz)

return LaunchDescription(l, run_rqt, run_rviz)
```

I'm running the launch script via `ros2 launch ...`

Is the passing of extra arguments handled correctly?
How do I fetch the values of these cli args at runtime?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322636/ros2-access-current-launchconfiguration/) by [bergercookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25299/bergercookie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 257 on 2019-05-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The launch argument's value is stored in the "Launch Configurations", and those can be accessed using a substitution called `launch.substitution.LaunchConfiguration(name) -> string`.

If you want to do something conditionally based on this, I'd recommend using a `launch.Condition` which may be passed to any `launch.Action`, e.g.:

```
def generate_launch_description():
    run_rqt_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        name="run_rqt",
        default_value="True",
        description="Launch RQT?")
    run_rviz_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        name="run_rviz",
        default_value="True",
        description="Launch RVIZ?")

    rqt = Node(...,
        condition=launch.conditions.IfCondition(launch.LaunchConfiguration("run_rqt")))
    rviz = Node(...,
        condition=launch.conditions.IfCondition(launch.LaunchConfiguration("run_rviz")))

    return launch.LaunchDescription([run_rqt_arg, run_rviz_arg, run_rqt, run_rviz])
```

See also:

- https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/d9def23d24b500c7c4b10f79297059b793b27152/launch/launch/actions/declare_launch_argument.py#L35-L37
- https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/d9def23d24b500c7c4b10f79297059b793b27152/launch/launch/action.py#L58

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2019-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [relffok](https://answers.ros.org/users/49523/relffok/) on 2019-12-26**:
Hi William, is this feature (`launch.substitution.LaunchConfiguration(name) -> string`) still supported in the current dashing version? I have been trying to use `launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration` to access my arguments but it does not return a string. Any ideas on that?

I have also opened a question for this: https://answers.ros.org/question/340705/access-launch-argument-in-launchfile-ros2/

**Comment by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on 2021-03-23**:
This is not supported anymore indeed.

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2021-07-05**:
So this answer is now out-of-date?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to evaluate launch arguments in a custom function outside of the LaunchDescription by using the OpaqueFunction launch action feature, see this link:

https://github.com/jrgnicho/collaborative-robotic-sanding/blob/3902e4f0e76bde226b18a997fd60fc30e1961212/crs_application/launch/perception.launch.py#L21

---

Originally posted by [jrgnicho](https://answers.ros.org/users/22410/jrgnicho/) with karma: 486 on 2020-08-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spoluri](https://answers.ros.org/users/74723/spoluri/) on 2021-08-26**:
I had the same issue of evaluating launch arguments. After a bit of struggle, the OpaqueFunction worked better than expected. My code is so much cleaner. Thank you for this!

ROS2 launch package definitely needs some documentation. It is a complete mystery right now.
If anyone has questions on how I managed to use OpaqueFunction, I can help you out.

**Comment by [ccpjBoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/81361/ccpjboss/) on 2022-03-10**:
Give @jrgnicho an award

**Comment by [chutsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34041/chutsu/) on 2023-04-16**:
Thanks for the tip @jrgnicho, I much prefer your workaround.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is an old question that is still being asked due to lack of examples in the ROS2 tutorial.  The best answer I have seen yet is by @djchopp

[https://answers.ros.org/question/382000/ros2-makes-launch-files-crazy-too-soon-to-be-migrating/#:~:text=%23!/usr/bin/env,condition%3DUnlessCondition(use_gui)%0A%20%20%20%20](https://answers.ros.org/question/382000/ros2-makes-launch-files-crazy-too-soon-to-be-migrating/#:%7E:text=%23!/usr/bin/env,condition%3DUnlessCondition(use_gui)%0A%20%20%20%20))%0A%0A%20%20%5D)

---

Originally posted by [RobotDreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/40559/robotdreams/) with karma: 327 on 2021-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2